# Linux sed remove 2 lines with pattern

Tags: bash, sed

I know how to remove all lines contening a pattern with

```
sed -i '/pattern/d' file
```

But how should I remove the line AND the next line ?

For example, with the following file, I want to remove all 'Apple' and next fruit

```
Apple
Peach
Lemon
Apple
Banana
Peach
```

Expected Output:

```
Lemon
Peach
```

Someone know how to do that ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Could you please try following(written and tested in GNU `sed`).

```
sed '/Apple/,+1 d' Input_file
```

Comment: I would accept this rather than mine. I know `+1` is a GNU extension but still

Answer (score 3):

Use `N` to read next line into pattern space.

```
sed '/Apple/{$!N;d}' file
```